# How to remove blank space around SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG showing on a simple web page, but once I resize the image beyond a certain size (height: ~65vh) the SVG has an invisible space around it that makes the page massive and have a scroll bar that goes down, and the image also has a large margin on the top. I've tried reducing the size of the viewbox in the SVG and setting the height and width in CSS. This is what the page looks like with the following code and snippet: I simply want the SVG to not have the massive border around it and just have the chip to manipulate the size of.
[image]

```css
.body {
  background-color: #660033;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CPU Animation / joshstroup.me</title>
</head>

<body>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0) -->
  <svg style="height: 70vh; margin-top: 40vh; overflow: hidden" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="500 500 1000 1000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2000 2000;"
  xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st0 {
        fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
      }
      .st1 {
        fill: #363636;
      }
      .st2 {
        fill: #FEFEFE;
      }
    </style>
    <g>
      <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M1000.4,1240.5c-79.7,0-159.4,0-239,0c-0.9,0-1.1-0.2-1.1-1.1c0-159.4,0-318.7,0-478.1c0-0.9,0.2-1.1,1.1-1.1 c159.4,0,318.7,0,478.1,0c0.9,0,1.1,0.2,1.1,1.1c0,159.4,0,318.7,0,478.1c0,0.9-0.2,1.1-1.1,1.1 C1159.7,1240.5,1080,1240.5,1000.4,1240.5z"
        />
        <path class="st1" d="M1017.4,1110.6c-3,0-6.1,0-9.1,0c-0.9,0-1.1,0.3-1.1,1.2c0,5,0,10.1,0,15.1c0,3-1.9,5.6-4.7,6.6 c-2.8,1-5.8,0.2-7.7-2c-1.2-1.4-1.7-2.9-1.7-4.7c0-5,0-9.9,0-14.9c0-0.9-0.2-1.2-1.2-1.2c-6.1,0-12.2,0-18.4,0 c-0.9,0-1.1,0.2-1.1,1.1c0,5,0,10.1,0,15.1c0,3.7-2.9,6.8-6.5,7c-3.7,0.3-6.9-2.3-7.5-6c-0.1-0.5-0.1-1-0.1-1.6 c0-4.8,0-9.6,0-14.4c0-1-0.2-1.4-1.3-1.3c-6,0.1-11.9,0.1-17.9,0c-1,0-1.3,0.2-1.3,1.2c0.1,5,0.1,10,0,15c0,3.7-2.9,6.8-6.5,7 c-3.7,0.3-6.9-2.3-7.5-6c-0.1-0.5-0.1-1-0.1-1.6c0-4.8,0-9.6,0-14.4c0-1.1-0.4-1.4-1.4-1.4c-5.2,0-10.4,0-15.6,0 c-9.7,0-17.1-7.4-17.1-17.1c0-5.2,0-10.3,0-15.5c0-1.2-0.2-1.6-1.5-1.5c-4.8,0.1-9.5,0.1-14.3,0c-3.7,0-6.8-2.9-7.1-6.5 c-0.3-3.7,2.3-6.9,6-7.5c0.5-0.1,1.1-0.1,1.7-0.1c4.7,0,9.4,0,14,0c0.9,0,1.1-0.3,1.1-1.2c0-6,0-12.1,0-18.1c0-1-0.3-1.2-1.2-1.2 c-4.7,0-9.4,0-14.2,0c-4.3,0-7.5-3.1-7.4-7.1c0-4,3.2-7,7.4-7c4.8,0,9.5,0,14.3,0c0.9,0,1.1-0.2,1.1-1.1c0-6.2,0-12.3,0-18.5 c0-0.9-0.3-1.1-1.1-1.1c-4.8,0-9.5,0-14.3,0c-4.3,0-7.5-3.1-7.5-7.1c0-4,3.2-7,7.4-7c4.8,0,9.5,0,14.3,0c0.9,0,1.2-0.2,1.1-1.1 c0-6.2,0-12.3,0-18.5c0-0.8-0.2-1.1-1.1-1.1c-4.8,0-9.5,0-14.3,0c-4.3,0-7.5-3.1-7.5-7.1c0-4,3.2-7,7.5-7.1c4.7,0,9.4,0,14,0 c1,0,1.3-0.2,1.3-1.2c-0.1-6,0-12,0-18c0-0.9-0.2-1.2-1.2-1.2c-4.7,0.1-9.4,0-14.2,0c-4.3,0-7.5-3-7.5-7.1c0-4,3.2-7.1,7.5-7.1 c4.6,0,9.2,0,13.8,0c1.7,0,1.5,0.2,1.5-1.6c0-5.1,0-10.2,0-15.4c0-9.8,7.3-17.1,17.2-17.2c5.2,0,10.4,0,15.6,0 c1,0,1.4-0.2,1.3-1.3c-0.1-4.4,0-8.7,0-13.1c0-4.3,3-7.5,7.1-7.5c4,0,7.1,3.2,7.1,7.5c0,4.4,0,8.8,0,13.2c0,0.8,0.1,1.2,1.1,1.2 c6.1,0,12.2,0,18.2,0c0.9,0,1.1-0.3,1.1-1.2c0-4.5,0-9,0-13.6c0-3.8,2.8-6.8,6.5-7.1c3.7-0.3,6.9,2.2,7.6,5.9 c0.1,0.6,0.1,1.2,0.1,1.8c0,4.4,0,8.7,0,13.1c0,0.8,0.2,1.1,1.1,1.1c6.2,0,12.3,0,18.5,0c0.9,0,1.1-0.3,1.1-1.2 c0-4.4,0-8.9,0-13.3c0-4.2,3.1-7.4,7-7.4c4,0,7.1,3.2,7.1,7.3c0,4.5,0,9,0,13.4c0,0.8,0.2,1.1,1.1,1.1c6.2,0,12.4,0,18.6,0 c0.8,0,1-0.2,1-1c0-4.6,0-9.1,0-13.7c0-3.8,2.8-6.8,6.4-7.1c3.7-0.3,6.9,2.2,7.6,5.9c0.1,0.7,0.1,1.4,0.1,2.2c0,4.2,0,8.4,0,12.6 c0,0.9,0.2,1.2,1.2,1.2c6,0,12.1,0,18.1,0c0.9,0,1.2-0.2,1.1-1.1c0-4.6,0-9.1,0-13.7c0-3.7,2.9-6.8,6.5-7c3.7-0.3,6.9,2.3,7.5,6 c0.1,0.7,0.1,1.4,0.1,2c0,4.1,0,8.2,0,12.2c0,1.8-0.2,1.6,1.5,1.6c5.1,0,10.2,0,15.4,0c9.9,0,17.2,7.3,17.2,17.2 c0,5.2,0,10.4,0,15.6c0,1,0.2,1.3,1.2,1.3c5.3-0.1,10.6,0,16,0c3.7,0,6.8,2.9,7,6.5c0.3,3.7-2.3,6.9-6,7.5 c-0.5,0.1-1.1,0.1-1.7,0.1c-5.1,0-10.2,0-15.4,0c-0.9,0-1.3,0.1-1.2,1.2c0.1,6,0,12.1,0,18.1c0,1,0.3,1.2,1.2,1.2 c5.4,0,10.7,0,16.1,0c3.5,0,6.3,2.6,6.9,6c0.5,3.3-1.5,6.6-4.7,7.7c-0.9,0.3-1.8,0.4-2.7,0.4c-5.2,0-10.4,0-15.6,0 c-0.9,0-1.1,0.3-1.1,1.1c0,6.1,0,12.2,0,18.4c0,1,0.3,1.2,1.2,1.2c5.4,0,10.7,0,16.1,0c3.5,0,6.3,2.6,6.9,6 c0.5,3.3-1.5,6.6-4.7,7.7c-0.9,0.3-1.8,0.4-2.7,0.4c-5.2,0-10.4,0-15.6,0c-0.9,0-1.1,0.2-1.1,1.1c0,6.2,0,12.3,0,18.5 c0,0.9,0.3,1.1,1.1,1.1c5.4,0,10.8,0,16.2,0c3.5,0,6.4,2.6,6.9,6.1c0.5,3.3-1.6,6.6-4.9,7.7c-0.8,0.3-1.7,0.4-2.6,0.4 c-5.2,0-10.4,0-15.6,0c-0.9,0-1.2,0.2-1.2,1.1c0,6.1,0,12.2,0,18.2c0,0.8,0.2,1.1,1.1,1.1c5.4,0,10.8,0,16.2,0 c3.5,0,6.4,2.6,6.9,6.1c0.5,3.3-1.6,6.6-4.8,7.7c-0.8,0.3-1.7,0.4-2.6,0.4c-5.1,0-10.2,0-15.4,0c-1,0-1.4,0.2-1.4,1.4 c0.1,5.2,0,10.4,0,15.6c0,9.8-7.4,17.1-17.2,17.1c-5.2,0-10.5,0-15.7,0c-0.9,0-1.2,0.2-1.2,1.2c0,5.1,0.1,10.2,0,15.2 c0,3.3-2.3,6-5.5,6.7c-3.1,0.7-6.3-0.8-7.8-3.6c-0.6-1.1-0.8-2.3-0.8-3.6c0-4.9,0-9.8,0-14.6c0-0.9-0.2-1.3-1.2-1.3 c-6,0.1-12,0.1-18,0c-1,0-1.2,0.3-1.2,1.3c0,5,0,9.9,0,14.9c0,3.8-2.8,6.8-6.5,7.1c-3.7,0.3-6.9-2.2-7.6-5.9 c-0.1-0.5-0.1-1.1-0.1-1.7c0-4.9,0-9.8,0-14.6c0-0.8-0.2-1.1-1.1-1.1C1023.7,1110.7,1020.5,1110.6,1017.4,1110.6z"
        />
        <path class="st2" d="M1000.1,938.6c20,0,40.1,0,60.1,0c1.1,0,1.5,0.2,1.5,1.4c0,40.1,0,80.2,0,120.3c0,1.1-0.2,1.4-1.4,1.4 c-40.2,0-80.3,0-120.5,0c-1,0-1.3-0.2-1.3-1.3c0-40.2,0-80.4,0-120.6c0-1.1,0.4-1.3,1.4-1.3C960,938.6,980.1,938.6,1000.1,938.6z"
        />
        <path class="st1" d="M1000.5,1040.6c-7.6,0-15.3,0-22.9,0c-8.3,0-15-5.3-16.8-13.5c-0.2-1.1-0.4-2.3-0.4-3.4c0-15.4,0-30.9,0-46.3 c0-9.5,7.5-16.9,17-16.9c15.4,0,30.8,0,46.2,0c9.5,0,17,7.5,17,17c0,15.4,0,30.8,0,46.2c0,9.6-7.5,17-17,17 C1015.8,1040.6,1008.2,1040.6,1000.5,1040.6z"
        />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I hope that is enough info and doesn't sound like rambling, if you need further info just ask

Comment: Try playing around with the `viewBox` property in the svg.

Comment: I have, I've tried tons of different values, the weird thing is the smaller I make the viewBox the larger it makes the invisible margins on the page around the SVG

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I opened your svg on Inkscape and resized the document size to fit the content. `(File -> Document Properties -> Resize page to content -> Resize page to drawing or selection)`

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    x="0px" y="0px"
    viewBox="500 500 268.2734 266.75002"
    style="enable-background:new 0 0 2000 2000;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:rgba(255,255,255,0);}
    .st1{fill:#363636;}
    .st2{fill:#FEFEFE;}
</style>
<path
   class="st1"
   d="m 651,743.42436 c -3,0 -6.1,0 -9.1,0 -0.9,0 -1.1,0.3 -1.1,1.2 0,5 0,10.1 0,15.1 0,3 -1.9,5.6 -4.7,6.6 -2.8,1 -5.8,0.2 -7.7,-2 -1.2,-1.4 -1.7,-2.9 -1.7,-4.7 0,-5 0,-9.9 0,-14.9 0,-0.9 -0.2,-1.2 -1.2,-1.2 -6.1,0 -12.2,0 -18.4,0 -0.9,0 -1.1,0.2 -1.1,1.1 0,5 0,10.1 0,15.1 0,3.7 -2.9,6.8 -6.5,7 -3.7,0.3 -6.9,-2.3 -7.5,-6 -0.1,-0.5 -0.1,-1 -0.1,-1.6 0,-4.8 0,-9.6 0,-14.4 0,-1 -0.2,-1.4 -1.3,-1.3 -6,0.1 -11.9,0.1 -17.9,0 -1,0 -1.3,0.2 -1.3,1.2 0.1,5 0.1,10 0,15 0,3.7 -2.9,6.8 -6.5,7 -3.7,0.3 -6.9,-2.3 -7.5,-6 -0.1,-0.5 -0.1,-1 -0.1,-1.6 0,-4.8 0,-9.6 0,-14.4 0,-1.1 -0.4,-1.4 -1.4,-1.4 -5.2,0 -10.4,0 -15.6,0 -9.7,0 -17.1,-7.4 -17.1,-17.1 0,-5.2 0,-10.3 0,-15.5 0,-1.2 -0.2,-1.6 -1.5,-1.5 -4.8,0.1 -9.5,0.1 -14.3,0 -3.7,0 -6.8,-2.9 -7.1,-6.5 -0.3,-3.7 2.3,-6.9 6,-7.5 0.5,-0.1 1.1,-0.1 1.7,-0.1 4.7,0 9.4,0 14,0 0.9,0 1.1,-0.3 1.1,-1.2 0,-6 0,-12.1 0,-18.1 0,-1 -0.3,-1.2 -1.2,-1.2 -4.7,0 -9.4,0 -14.2,0 -4.3,0 -7.5,-3.1 -7.4,-7.1 0,-4 3.2,-7 7.4,-7 4.8,0 9.5,0 14.3,0 0.9,0 1.1,-0.2 1.1,-1.1 0,-6.2 0,-12.3 0,-18.5 0,-0.9 -0.3,-1.1 -1.1,-1.1 -4.8,0 -9.5,0 -14.3,0 -4.3,0 -7.5,-3.1 -7.5,-7.1 0,-4 3.2,-7 7.4,-7 4.8,0 9.5,0 14.3,0 0.9,0 1.2,-0.2 1.1,-1.1 0,-6.2 0,-12.3 0,-18.5 0,-0.8 -0.2,-1.1 -1.1,-1.1 -4.8,0 -9.5,0 -14.3,0 -4.3,0 -7.5,-3.1 -7.5,-7.1 0,-4 3.2,-7 7.5,-7.1 4.7,0 9.4,0 14,0 1,0 1.3,-0.2 1.3,-1.2 -0.1,-6 0,-12 0,-18 0,-0.9 -0.2,-1.2 -1.2,-1.2 -4.7,0.1 -9.4,0 -14.2,0 -4.3,0 -7.5,-3 -7.5,-7.1 0,-4 3.2,-7.1 7.5,-7.1 4.6,0 9.2,0 13.8,0 1.7,0 1.5,0.2 1.5,-1.6 0,-5.1 0,-10.2 0,-15.4 0,-9.8 7.3,-17.1 17.2,-17.2 5.2,0 10.4,0 15.6,0 1,0 1.4,-0.2 1.3,-1.3 -0.1,-4.4 0,-8.7 0,-13.1 0,-4.3 3,-7.5 7.1,-7.5 4,0 7.1,3.2 7.1,7.5 0,4.4 0,8.8 0,13.2 0,0.8 0.1,1.2 1.1,1.2 6.1,0 12.2,0 18.2,0 0.9,0 1.1,-0.3 1.1,-1.2 0,-4.5 0,-9 0,-13.6 0,-3.8 2.8,-6.8 6.5,-7.1 3.7,-0.3 6.9,2.2 7.6,5.9 0.1,0.6 0.1,1.2 0.1,1.8 0,4.4 0,8.7 0,13.1 0,0.8 0.2,1.1 1.1,1.1 6.2,0 12.3,0 18.5,0 0.9,0 1.1,-0.3 1.1,-1.2 0,-4.4 0,-8.9 0,-13.3 0,-4.2 3.1,-7.4 7,-7.4 4,0 7.1,3.2 7.1,7.3 0,4.5 0,9 0,13.4 0,0.8 0.2,1.1 1.1,1.1 6.2,0 12.4,0 18.6,0 0.8,0 1,-0.2 1,-1 0,-4.6 0,-9.1 0,-13.7 0,-3.8 2.8,-6.8 6.4,-7.1 3.7,-0.3 6.9,2.2 7.6,5.9 0.1,0.7 0.1,1.4 0.1,2.2 0,4.2 0,8.4 0,12.6 0,0.9 0.2,1.2 1.2,1.2 6,0 12.1,0 18.1,0 0.9,0 1.2,-0.2 1.1,-1.1 0,-4.6 0,-9.1 0,-13.7 0,-3.7 2.9,-6.8 6.5,-7 3.7,-0.3 6.9,2.3 7.5,6 0.1,0.7 0.1,1.4 0.1,2 0,4.1 0,8.2 0,12.2 0,1.8 -0.2,1.6 1.5,1.6 5.1,0 10.2,0 15.4,0 9.9,0 17.2,7.3 17.2,17.2 0,5.2 0,10.4 0,15.6 0,1 0.2,1.3 1.2,1.3 5.3,-0.1 10.6,0 16,0 3.7,0 6.8,2.9 7,6.5 0.3,3.7 -2.3,6.9 -6,7.5 -0.5,0.1 -1.1,0.1 -1.7,0.1 -5.1,0 -10.2,0 -15.4,0 -0.9,0 -1.3,0.1 -1.2,1.2 0.1,6 0,12.1 0,18.1 0,1 0.3,1.2 1.2,1.2 5.4,0 10.7,0 16.1,0 3.5,0 6.3,2.6 6.9,6 0.5,3.3 -1.5,6.6 -4.7,7.7 -0.9,0.3 -1.8,0.4 -2.7,0.4 -5.2,0 -10.4,0 -15.6,0 -0.9,0 -1.1,0.3 -1.1,1.1 0,6.1 0,12.2 0,18.4 0,1 0.3,1.2 1.2,1.2 5.4,0 10.7,0 16.1,0 3.5,0 6.3,2.6 6.9,6 0.5,3.3 -1.5,6.6 -4.7,7.7 -0.9,0.3 -1.8,0.4 -2.7,0.4 -5.2,0 -10.4,0 -15.6,0 -0.9,0 -1.1,0.2 -1.1,1.1 0,6.2 0,12.3 0,18.5 0,0.9 0.3,1.1 1.1,1.1 5.4,0 10.8,0 16.2,0 3.5,0 6.4,2.6 6.9,6.1 0.5,3.3 -1.6,6.6 -4.9,7.7 -0.8,0.3 -1.7,0.4 -2.6,0.4 -5.2,0 -10.4,0 -15.6,0 -0.9,0 -1.2,0.2 -1.2,1.1 0,6.1 0,12.2 0,18.2 0,0.8 0.2,1.1 1.1,1.1 5.4,0 10.8,0 16.2,0 3.5,0 6.4,2.6 6.9,6.1 0.5,3.3 -1.6,6.6 -4.8,7.7 -0.8,0.3 -1.7,0.4 -2.6,0.4 -5.1,0 -10.2,0 -15.4,0 -1,0 -1.4,0.2 -1.4,1.4 0.1,5.2 0,10.4 0,15.6 0,9.8 -7.4,17.1 -17.2,17.1 -5.2,0 -10.5,0 -15.7,0 -0.9,0 -1.2,0.2 -1.2,1.2 0,5.1 0.1,10.2 0,15.2 0,3.3 -2.3,6 -5.5,6.7 -3.1,0.7 -6.3,-0.8 -7.8,-3.6 -0.6,-1.1 -0.8,-2.3 -0.8,-3.6 0,-4.9 0,-9.8 0,-14.6 0,-0.9 -0.2,-1.3 -1.2,-1.3 -6,0.1 -12,0.1 -18,0 -1,0 -1.2,0.3 -1.2,1.3 0,5 0,9.9 0,14.9 0,3.8 -2.8,6.8 -6.5,7.1 -3.7,0.3 -6.9,-2.2 -7.6,-5.9 -0.1,-0.5 -0.1,-1.1 -0.1,-1.7 0,-4.9 0,-9.8 0,-14.6 0,-0.8 -0.2,-1.1 -1.1,-1.1 -2.7,0.4 -5.9,0.3 -9,0.3 z"
   id="path11"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   style="fill:#363636" /><path
   class="st2"
   d="m 633.7,571.42436 c 20,0 40.1,0 60.1,0 1.1,0 1.5,0.2 1.5,1.4 0,40.1 0,80.2 0,120.3 0,1.1 -0.2,1.4 -1.4,1.4 -40.2,0 -80.3,0 -120.5,0 -1,0 -1.3,-0.2 -1.3,-1.3 0,-40.2 0,-80.4 0,-120.6 0,-1.1 0.4,-1.3 1.4,-1.3 20.1,0.1 40.2,0.1 60.2,0.1 z"
   id="path13"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   style="fill:#fefefe" /><path
   class="st1"
   d="m 634.1,673.42436 c -7.6,0 -15.3,0 -22.9,0 -8.3,0 -15,-5.3 -16.8,-13.5 -0.2,-1.1 -0.4,-2.3 -0.4,-3.4 0,-15.4 0,-30.9 0,-46.3 0,-9.5 7.5,-16.9 17,-16.9 15.4,0 30.8,0 46.2,0 9.5,0 17,7.5 17,17 0,15.4 0,30.8 0,46.2 0,9.6 -7.5,17 -17,17 -7.8,-0.1 -15.4,-0.1 -23.1,-0.1 z"
   id="path15"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   style="fill:#363636" />
</svg>
```

Now that the svg was fixed, you can put it in your file and set the height. In this case `height:70vh;` (For performance reasons, it's recommended to set height and width, but it's up to you).

```css
#Layer_1{ /*Change svg id to a meaningful name*/
    height:70vh
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CPU Animation / joshstroup.me</title>
</head>

<body>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    x="0px" y="0px"
    viewBox="500 500 268.2734 266.75002"
    style="enable-background:new 0 0 2000 2000;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:rgba(255,255,255,0);}
    .st1{fill:#363636;}
    .st2{fill:#FEFEFE;}
</style>
<path
   class="st1"
   d="m 651,743.42436 c -3,0 -6.1,0 -9.1,0 -0.9,0 -1.1,0.3 -1.1,1.2 0,5 0,10.1 0,15.1 0,3 -1.9,5.6 -4.7,6.6 -2.8,1 -5.8,0.2 -7.7,-2 -1.2,-1.4 -1.7,-2.9 -1.7,-4.7 0,-5 0,-9.9 0,-14.9 0,-0.9 -0.2,-1.2 -1.2,-1.2 -6.1,0 -12.2,0 -18.4,0 -0.9,0 -1.1,0.2 -1.1,1.1 0,5 0,10.1 0,15.1 0,3.7 -2.9,6.8 -6.5,7 -3.7,0.3 -6.9,-2.3 -7.5,-6 -0.1,-0.5 -0.1,-1 -0.1,-1.6 0,-4.8 0,-9.6 0,-14.4 0,-1 -0.2,-1.4 -1.3,-1.3 -6,0.1 -11.9,0.1 -17.9,0 -1,0 -1.3,0.2 -1.3,1.2 0.1,5 0.1,10 0,15 0,3.7 -2.9,6.8 -6.5,7 -3.7,0.3 -6.9,-2.3 -7.5,-6 -0.1,-0.5 -0.1,-1 -0.1,-1.6 0,-4.8 0,-9.6 0,-14.4 0,-1.1 -0.4,-1.4 -1.4,-1.4 -5.2,0 -10.4,0 -15.6,0 -9.7,0 -17.1,-7.4 -17.1,-17.1 0,-5.2 0,-10.3 0,-15.5 0,-1.2 -0.2,-1.6 -1.5,-1.5 -4.8,0.1 -9.5,0.1 -14.3,0 -3.7,0 -6.8,-2.9 -7.1,-6.5 -0.3,-3.7 2.3,-6.9 6,-7.5 0.5,-0.1 1.1,-0.1 1.7,-0.1 4.7,0 9.4,0 14,0 0.9,0 1.1,-0.3 1.1,-1.2 0,-6 0,-12.1 0,-18.1 0,-1 -0.3,-1.2 -1.2,-1.2 -4.7,0 -9.4,0 -14.2,0 -4.3,0 -7.5,-3.1 -7.4,-7.1 0,-4 3.2,-7 7.4,-7 4.8,0 9.5,0 14.3,0 0.9,0 1.1,-0.2 1.1,-1.1 0,-6.2 0,-12.3 0,-18.5 0,-0.9 -0.3,-1.1 -1.1,-1.1 -4.8,0 -9.5,0 -14.3,0 -4.3,0 -7.5,-3.1 -7.5,-7.1 0,-4 3.2,-7 7.4,-7 4.8,0 9.5,0 14.3,0 0.9,0 1.2,-0.2 1.1,-1.1 0,-6.2 0,-12.3 0,-18.5 0,-0.8 -0.2,-1.1 -1.1,-1.1 -4.8,0 -9.5,0 -14.3,0 -4.3,0 -7.5,-3.1 -7.5,-7.1 0,-4 3.2,-7 7.5,-7.1 4.7,0 9.4,0 14,0 1,0 1.3,-0.2 1.3,-1.2 -0.1,-6 0,-12 0,-18 0,-0.9 -0.2,-1.2 -1.2,-1.2 -4.7,0.1 -9.4,0 -14.2,0 -4.3,0 -7.5,-3 -7.5,-7.1 0,-4 3.2,-7.1 7.5,-7.1 4.6,0 9.2,0 13.8,0 1.7,0 1.5,0.2 1.5,-1.6 0,-5.1 0,-10.2 0,-15.4 0,-9.8 7.3,-17.1 17.2,-17.2 5.2,0 10.4,0 15.6,0 1,0 1.4,-0.2 1.3,-1.3 -0.1,-4.4 0,-8.7 0,-13.1 0,-4.3 3,-7.5 7.1,-7.5 4,0 7.1,3.2 7.1,7.5 0,4.4 0,8.8 0,13.2 0,0.8 0.1,1.2 1.1,1.2 6.1,0 12.2,0 18.2,0 0.9,0 1.1,-0.3 1.1,-1.2 0,-4.5 0,-9 0,-13.6 0,-3.8 2.8,-6.8 6.5,-7.1 3.7,-0.3 6.9,2.2 7.6,5.9 0.1,0.6 0.1,1.2 0.1,1.8 0,4.4 0,8.7 0,13.1 0,0.8 0.2,1.1 1.1,1.1 6.2,0 12.3,0 18.5,0 0.9,0 1.1,-0.3 1.1,-1.2 0,-4.4 0,-8.9 0,-13.3 0,-4.2 3.1,-7.4 7,-7.4 4,0 7.1,3.2 7.1,7.3 0,4.5 0,9 0,13.4 0,0.8 0.2,1.1 1.1,1.1 6.2,0 12.4,0 18.6,0 0.8,0 1,-0.2 1,-1 0,-4.6 0,-9.1 0,-13.7 0,-3.8 2.8,-6.8 6.4,-7.1 3.7,-0.3 6.9,2.2 7.6,5.9 0.1,0.7 0.1,1.4 0.1,2.2 0,4.2 0,8.4 0,12.6 0,0.9 0.2,1.2 1.2,1.2 6,0 12.1,0 18.1,0 0.9,0 1.2,-0.2 1.1,-1.1 0,-4.6 0,-9.1 0,-13.7 0,-3.7 2.9,-6.8 6.5,-7 3.7,-0.3 6.9,2.3 7.5,6 0.1,0.7 0.1,1.4 0.1,2 0,4.1 0,8.2 0,12.2 0,1.8 -0.2,1.6 1.5,1.6 5.1,0 10.2,0 15.4,0 9.9,0 17.2,7.3 17.2,17.2 0,5.2 0,10.4 0,15.6 0,1 0.2,1.3 1.2,1.3 5.3,-0.1 10.6,0 16,0 3.7,0 6.8,2.9 7,6.5 0.3,3.7 -2.3,6.9 -6,7.5 -0.5,0.1 -1.1,0.1 -1.7,0.1 -5.1,0 -10.2,0 -15.4,0 -0.9,0 -1.3,0.1 -1.2,1.2 0.1,6 0,12.1 0,18.1 0,1 0.3,1.2 1.2,1.2 5.4,0 10.7,0 16.1,0 3.5,0 6.3,2.6 6.9,6 0.5,3.3 -1.5,6.6 -4.7,7.7 -0.9,0.3 -1.8,0.4 -2.7,0.4 -5.2,0 -10.4,0 -15.6,0 -0.9,0 -1.1,0.3 -1.1,1.1 0,6.1 0,12.2 0,18.4 0,1 0.3,1.2 1.2,1.2 5.4,0 10.7,0 16.1,0 3.5,0 6.3,2.6 6.9,6 0.5,3.3 -1.5,6.6 -4.7,7.7 -0.9,0.3 -1.8,0.4 -2.7,0.4 -5.2,0 -10.4,0 -15.6,0 -0.9,0 -1.1,0.2 -1.1,1.1 0,6.2 0,12.3 0,18.5 0,0.9 0.3,1.1 1.1,1.1 5.4,0 10.8,0 16.2,0 3.5,0 6.4,2.6 6.9,6.1 0.5,3.3 -1.6,6.6 -4.9,7.7 -0.8,0.3 -1.7,0.4 -2.6,0.4 -5.2,0 -10.4,0 -15.6,0 -0.9,0 -1.2,0.2 -1.2,1.1 0,6.1 0,12.2 0,18.2 0,0.8 0.2,1.1 1.1,1.1 5.4,0 10.8,0 16.2,0 3.5,0 6.4,2.6 6.9,6.1 0.5,3.3 -1.6,6.6 -4.8,7.7 -0.8,0.3 -1.7,0.4 -2.6,0.4 -5.1,0 -10.2,0 -15.4,0 -1,0 -1.4,0.2 -1.4,1.4 0.1,5.2 0,10.4 0,15.6 0,9.8 -7.4,17.1 -17.2,17.1 -5.2,0 -10.5,0 -15.7,0 -0.9,0 -1.2,0.2 -1.2,1.2 0,5.1 0.1,10.2 0,15.2 0,3.3 -2.3,6 -5.5,6.7 -3.1,0.7 -6.3,-0.8 -7.8,-3.6 -0.6,-1.1 -0.8,-2.3 -0.8,-3.6 0,-4.9 0,-9.8 0,-14.6 0,-0.9 -0.2,-1.3 -1.2,-1.3 -6,0.1 -12,0.1 -18,0 -1,0 -1.2,0.3 -1.2,1.3 0,5 0,9.9 0,14.9 0,3.8 -2.8,6.8 -6.5,7.1 -3.7,0.3 -6.9,-2.2 -7.6,-5.9 -0.1,-0.5 -0.1,-1.1 -0.1,-1.7 0,-4.9 0,-9.8 0,-14.6 0,-0.8 -0.2,-1.1 -1.1,-1.1 -2.7,0.4 -5.9,0.3 -9,0.3 z"
   id="path11"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   style="fill:#363636" /><path
   class="st2"
   d="m 633.7,571.42436 c 20,0 40.1,0 60.1,0 1.1,0 1.5,0.2 1.5,1.4 0,40.1 0,80.2 0,120.3 0,1.1 -0.2,1.4 -1.4,1.4 -40.2,0 -80.3,0 -120.5,0 -1,0 -1.3,-0.2 -1.3,-1.3 0,-40.2 0,-80.4 0,-120.6 0,-1.1 0.4,-1.3 1.4,-1.3 20.1,0.1 40.2,0.1 60.2,0.1 z"
   id="path13"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   style="fill:#fefefe" /><path
   class="st1"
   d="m 634.1,673.42436 c -7.6,0 -15.3,0 -22.9,0 -8.3,0 -15,-5.3 -16.8,-13.5 -0.2,-1.1 -0.4,-2.3 -0.4,-3.4 0,-15.4 0,-30.9 0,-46.3 0,-9.5 7.5,-16.9 17,-16.9 15.4,0 30.8,0 46.2,0 9.5,0 17,7.5 17,17 0,15.4 0,30.8 0,46.2 0,9.6 -7.5,17 -17,17 -7.8,-0.1 -15.4,-0.1 -23.1,-0.1 z"
   id="path15"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   style="fill:#363636" />
</svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried that as well, once again as with decreasing the size of the viewBox, it just makes the image look bigger and the invisible margins smaller, while keeping the entire SVG the same size

Comment: I added a snippet now @dap.tci

Comment: @Wargog, I changed my answer. Please, take a look.

Comment: So, what all have you changed, I see the styling is now in the SVG itself, but other than that was has changed? Once I see that, I'll mark accepted, thanks.

Comment: I remade the answer explaining better and removing the inline styling in the SVG. If it's not clear already, let me know.

Answer (score 21):

<strike>I made this codepen that might help others who don't want to deal with drawing tools:</strike>

<strike>https://codepen.io/Steve6886/pen/abzzdOG</strike>

EDIT: Here’s a more up-to-date version of my previous codepen solution: https://svgcrop.com

```
// USER: Set either a width OR height (will scale evenly)
const WIDTH = 100;
const HEIGHT = null;

// Grab the SVG and remove any existing viewBox
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
svg.removeAttribute('viewBox');

// Set default coordinates
const coords = {
  top: Infinity,
  left: Infinity,
  bottom: -Infinity,
  right: -Infinity
}; 

// Filter SVG to visible elements
filterize = newSvg => {
  const newest = [...newSvg.children].filter(x => x.tagName !== 'defs' && x.tagName !== 'style' && x.tagName !== 'title' && x.tagName !== 'desc');
  if ((newest.length === 1 && newest.childElementCount > 0) || newest[0].tagName === 'g') {
    return filterize(newest[0]);  
  }  

  return newest.filter(x => (x.getBoundingClientRect().top !== 0 && x.getBoundingClientRect().left !== 0 && x.getBoundingClientRect().bottom !== 0 && x.getBoundingClientRect().right !== 0));
  
} 

// Get coordinates of SVG elements
filterize(svg).forEach(x => {
  const {top, left, bottom, right} = x.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (top < coords.top) {
    coords.top = x.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  }
  if (left < coords.left) {
    coords.left = x.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  }
  if (right > coords.right) {
    coords.right = x.getBoundingClientRect().right;
  }
  if (bottom > coords.bottom) {
    coords.bottom = x.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
  }
}); 

// Set viewBox based on coordinates
svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `${coords.left.toFixed(2)} ${coords.top.toFixed(2)} ${(coords.right - coords.left).toFixed(2)} ${(coords.bottom - coords.top).toFixed(2)}`);

// Set given width OR height
WIDTH && svg.setAttribute('width', WIDTH);
HEIGHT && svg.setAttribute('height', HEIGHT);  

// Add textarea with new SVG code to copy
const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
textarea.style = `display:block;margin-top:2rem;width:100%;padding:0;min-height:calc(100vh - ${getComputedStyle(svg).height} - 2rem);`;
textarea.innerHTML = svg.outerHTML;
document.body.appendChild(textarea);
```

Comment: Good job! I used your code and, what's more, it helped me to realize that the view box may not start with 0 0 as a left bottom point - sometimes the proper coords can be set manually in case of simple images. Thank you.

Comment: This is awesome. That is all. Thank you :)

Comment: Great Job, i was looking this for a long time.

Comment: svgcrop is a lifesaver, will try to donate soon.

Comment: You've just saved my day! Thanks