# How to define padding for responsive svg

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, responsive

up to some tutorial, in order to make some d3.js svg visualization responsive we proceed as follow.

We include our svgs in the index.html like this:

```
        <div class="col-8" data-step="8" data-intro="How cool is this barchart?"> <!-- BAR -->
            <div class="svg-container" style="padding-bottom: 20%">
                <svg id="bar" viewBox="0 0 1000 275" class="svg-content"  preserveAspectRatio="none"></svg>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then in the javascript we create an svg which has dimension 1000x275 which is binded to the svg element by id.

In the css we define as follow:

```
.svg-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.svg-content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

When you resize the page, the browser resize the svg and it works pretty well. The problem is that using the padding like this, the svg ends up having some enormous bottom padding taking a lot of space which is not required.

What should we change in our definitions to solve this problem?

Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877301/how-to-remove-blank-space-around-svg I think this might help you

Comment: thank you, I still don't understand, why in our case the svg content is not crop to the svg container? (it goes outside)

Comment: Try adding `bottom:0;` to the `.svg-content`, too. Does that do anything different? Also, is that inline `padding-bottom:20px` still necessary?